# In HTML is it possible for normal `<A/>` link to produce POST request?

Tags: html, http

It is possible to use a HTML anchor link...

```
<a href="foo?bar=baz">link</a>
```

...to produce a GET request to `foo` with query params `bar=baz`.

Is it also possible to write the anchor link in such a way that it produces a POST request to `foo` with the params `bar=baz` encoded in the HTTP request body (like a form with method POST does) ?

Comment: Not with plain html. If you're willing to use javascript, then it can be done.

Comment: If you send it to a PHP page, it could probably do the request for you.

Comment: Use a `<form>` if you want a JS-less POST.

Comment: in order to evaluate we have to use javascript for client side or use any backend language

Comment: As the answer is emphatic no, it would be useful to explain why you would do this (so that then best way to achieve that could be found).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: Well for one reason the browser warns about resubmission of POST requests (for example on refresh or on back), whereas it does not for GET requests with query params.  This is problematic if the action is not idempotent.  For another reason it complicates the backend to have two different ways of submitting parameters.

Comment: So how does this relate to using a link to submit a POST request?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: If the links result in POST requests and not GET requests - than the target requests will have the properties I just described.  It would be a lot more conveniance to have something like `<a method="POST" href="foo?bar=baz">link</a>` possible than to have the solutions described in the answers.

Comment: Why would you use a link for a non-idempotent request?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: For example, take this page: We have `[share] | [edit] | [close] | etc` text links that result in actions that you wouldn't want to accidentally repeat and have parameters.

Comment: Actions are normally expressed using buttons. You have not described why links should be used here.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: What is the difference between a link and a button?

Answer (score 1):

No

Alternatives: You can modify the request made by the anchor tag using javascript,

or

use a form, and emulate a anchor by styling the submit button to look like a link

Answer (score 0):

In the html file the anchor file doesn't support the POST values.

You can get the post values for html file only through the form tag.

`<form action="test.php" method="post" >
<input type="text" name="lname" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hidden form with the values you want to submit; and you link can trigger the `submit()` action on that form. This is easily done with jquery (or your favorite javascript library).

This is untested, but something like this should do it:

```
<form method="POST" id="the_form" action="foo/">
  <input type="hidden" name="bar" value="baz" />
</form>

<a href="#" id="submit_link">Send values</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#submit_link').click($('#the_form').submit());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Matt Ball commented, you can accomplish this with a form and no JS:

```
<form method="post" action="YOUR_ACTION">
    <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar" />
    <input type="submit" value="link" class="submitLink" />
</form>
```

and then style the submit to look like a regular link:

```
<style type="text/css">
input.submitLink {
    background: none;
    border: medium none;
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>
```