# View components can't link to POST action methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I have a view component which contains some action links that points to different action methods in the home controller, like this:

```
<a asp-action="Update" asp-route-id="@item.ProductId">Update quantity</a>
<a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ProductId">@item.ProductTitle</a>
```

The action method `Details`, which is a `GET`-method, is being executed as expected.

But when I click on the `Update`-link, I'm directed to a blank page with the url of /Home/Update/5, for instance, and nothing more happens. This is also the case even if I run in debug mode and set a breakpoint on the first line of the `Update`-method. `Update` is a `POST`-method. Does this matter?

In either case, `Update` is not executed.

What is going on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In HTML is it possible for normal \`<A/>\` link to produce POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241773/in-html-is-it-possible-for-normal-a-link-to-produce-post-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call POST request by clicking a link.

You either need to use ajax or form for this. 
It depends on your needs.

Use form:

```
<form asp-action="Update" asp-route-id="@item.ProductId" method="post">
    <button type="submit">Update quantity</button>
</form>
```

Use ajax: (assume you have jQuery)

```
$('<update-link-selector>').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    $.post(href).done(function(response, status, xhr) {
        //success 
    }).fail(function(err) {
        //error
    });
});
```

Comment: Just to add, when you click a link (and the click is not intercepted by JS), your browser will do an HTTP GET on that URL. To do a POST (or use any other method), you *must* use a form or AJAX in JavaScript.